# Disable/suppress tcltk popup for CRAN mirror selection in R

Tags: r, user-interface, popup, x11, cran

My question is similar to a question previously posted but never really answered here:

[Disable GUI, graphics devices in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339630/disable-gui-graphics-devices-in-r)

I do not like the R tcltk popups for CRAN mirror selection. They also pop up to choose a package when searching for help on a function in two packages.

Is there any way to disable these windows without disabling X11 completely? I still want plot() commands to work as normal, but disable the little select menus that take forever to load over a remote connection.

For example, if you use ssh, but don't use -X, then the mirror select is just text within R, you type a number. It's fast. This is what I want, but maintaining X11 for plots b.

Anyone know how to maintain graphics windows but disable the "choice" tcltk windows?

Comment: A pet peeve of mine too! `Rstudio` plots graphics with X window but blocks the ugly Tcl/tk popup. Thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Dirk provides ways to avoid the menus altogether, but to answer your question as posed, I think you want

```
options(menu.graphics=FALSE)
```

I tracked this option down by finding the class of objects returned from `help` (it's `help_files_with_topic`), scanning `utils:::print.help_files_with_topic` and finding the line

```
menu(txt, title = gettext("Choose one"), graphics = getOption("menu.graphics"))
```

Comment: Yes! That is what I was looking for. I had looked in that options menu...Not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 12):

Just **set a mirror** in the startup files.  I have this in my `~/.Rprofile` and I never see that prompt:

```
## Default repo
local({r <- getOption("repos");
       r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.us.r-project.org"; 
       options(repos=r)})
```

See `help(Startup)` for more things you can customize here, and also see [this excellent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile) on customizing `~/.Rprofile`.

*Edit:* As for your additional question just added in the comments, that is different. In this case you could specify the `mapply` explicitly by using the namespace and `::` operator. For example, `base::mapply(foo, bar)` would unambiguously pick one from the standard library, and similarly `help(mapply, package="base")` asks for the help for a given function from a given package.

Comment: Alright, this solves for the mirror, but what about the "Choose one" dialog that comes up when you type "?mapply" and have 2 packages with "mapply" functions (like IRanges and base)? Loading Tcl/Tk interface...

Comment: Ah well, with such an endorsement I just had to nitpick again :)

Comment: Now see what your nitpicking has done - the answer disappeared !  ;-)

Comment: -1 for not answering the original question. Adding a "have you tried this instead?" comment is fine, but suggested alternatives may not apply in the OP's context, let alone the context of each person who has the same question, possibly even years later. Therefore they don't constitute an answer to the specific question asked.

Comment: Years later, but just wanted to defend Dirk (not that he needs it...); for most people searching for this question, this is almost certainly an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where Dirk's answer is going to answer their underlying question better than my accepted answer will.

Answer (score 2):

Also have a look at the [interactivity](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/interactivity/index.html) package in CRAN if you wish to completley disable interactive funky stuff.

Comment: `interactivity` package has been removed from CRAN and doesn't seem to be available anywhere. Has it been mothballed? Which package to use instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the repo within the `install.packages()` call.  This was tested on `R/4.3.0`, e.g.

`install.packages("withr", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`

Answer (score 0):

Place this on a new line in `~/.Rprofile`:

```
options(repos=c(CRAN="http://cran.r-project.org"))
```

Restart your R session and the CRAN mirror popup again won't hassle you again!

NOTE: if ~/.Rprofile doesn't exist, you can simply create it. Don't forget the . (that makes it a hidden file).

#### Alternate approach (macOS, linux)

You can just run this once in your terminal (it will append the line mentioned above to the bottom of your ~/.Rprofile file! (saving you having to track it down and manually edit it). Restart your R session so it takes effect, and the CRAN mirror popup won't appear again.

```bash
echo 'options(repos=c(CRAN="http://cran.r-project.org"))' >> ~/.Rprofile
```

#### Note

You can set any CRAN mirror you want, `"http://cran.r-project.org"` is used above because it's a common one.

#### Source

This useful info comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8475208/5783745).