# Set default CRAN mirror permanent in R

Tags: r, cran, r-faq

How can I set a specific CRAN mirror permanently in R?

I want to set it permanently in my laptop so that when I do `install.packages()`, it won't ask me again which mirror to choose.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile for .Rprofile examples.

Comment: you may want to edit global `Rprofile` file. On *NIX platforms, it's located in `/usr/lib/R/library/base/R/Rprofile`. Just be careful... and note that local `.Rprofile` settings take precedence.

Comment: Following up on @aL3xa's comment, see `?Startup` for the really gory details of where `.Rprofile files can be located and which take precedence.

Comment: And please notice the `.First` and `.Last` objects.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You can set *repos* in your *.Rprofile* to restore your choice every time you start R

**Edit:** to be more precise:

Add

```
options(repos=c(CRAN="THE URL OF YOUR FAVORITE MIRROR"))
```

to your *.Rprofile*, located in the home directory of your user.

You can find a list of CRAN mirrors [here](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html).

**Example**:

```r
# add this line to ~/.Rprofile, restart your R session so it takes effect
options(repos=c(CRAN="http://cran.r-project.org"))
```

---

Alternatively, you can set the mirror site-wide in your `Rprofile.site`. The location of the file is given by `?Startup`:

> The
> path of this file is taken from the value of the `R_PROFILE`
> environment variable (after tilde expansion).  If this variable is
> unset, the default is `R_HOME/etc/Rprofile.site`, which is used if
> it exists (which it does not in a 'factory-fresh' installation).

So do `Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE")` for the first option, or `Sys.getenv("R_HOME")` or `R.home()` for the second option. On macOS, the location of the second is `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/`.

The file may not exist, or you may see the following lines commented out :

```
# set a CRAN mirror
# local({r <- getOption("repos")
#       r["CRAN"] <- "http://my.local.cran"
#       options(repos=r)})
```

So remove the comment marks and change "http://my.local.cran" to the correct website, e.g.:

```r
local({r <- getOption("repos")
       r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.r-project.org"
       options(repos=r)})
```

Comment: I added extra information, as it wasn't worth an extra answer and a bit too much for a comment.

Comment: I don't think that call to `structure` is doing anything.  Usually it's just a convenient way to add attributes to an object.

Comment: @rinni: thanks, I googled for the list of URLs found the one I am closest to as you described in the `.Rprofile` file.

Comment: There does not seem to be a `RProfile.site` file in my R 3.3.1 on Arch Linux x86_64. There is a file named `RProfile` that does not contain the commented out lines mentioned in the answer.

Comment: where "YOUR FAVORITE MIRROR" is the URL, not the name.

Answer (score 1):

In one instance, the .Rprofile edit suggested above did not work. However, the following code did:

```
utils::setRepositories(ind = 0, addURLs = c(CRAN = "YOUR FAVORITE MIRROR"))
```

where "YOUR FAVORITE MIRROR" is the URL, not the name.

Restart R after editing the .Rprofile. `ind = 0` will indicate that you only want the named repository. Additional repositories can be included in the `addURLs =` option and are comma separated within the character vector.

Comment: I'm using RStudio (Version 2023.06.1+524) on Mac (Ventura) and this was what worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

In case you are trying to do this in RStudio, you can either do it via the RStudio UI (Tools -> Global Options -> Packages) or use the file `~/.config/rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json` and put the following inside for `https://cran.rstudio.com/`.

```
{
    "cran_mirror": {
        "name": "Global (CDN)",
        "host": "RStudio",
        "url": "https://cran.rstudio.com/",
        "country": "us",
        "ok": 1,
        "secondary": ""
    }
}
```

Probably you already have other options set within so you can just add `cran_mirror` to the list.

The full file on my current system (`RStudio Server 2022.02.2 Build 485`, `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`) looks like this:

```
{
    "initial_working_directory": "~",
    "margin_column": 120,
    "scroll_past_end_of_document": true,
    "highlight_r_function_calls": true,
    "rainbow_parentheses": true,
    "posix_terminal_shell": "bash",
    "default_project_location": "~",
    "jobs_tab_visibility": "shown",
    "source_with_echo": true,
    "save_workspace": "never",
    "load_workspace": false,
    "always_save_history": false,
    "data_viewer_max_columns": 500,
    "cran_mirror": {
        "name": "Global (CDN)",
        "host": "RStudio",
        "url": "https://cran.rstudio.com/",
        "country": "us",
        "ok": 1,
        "secondary": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Running rstudio server from the rocker/ml image, this does change the repo that shows up in the tools window for me, but doesn't seem to have any other effects (`getOption("repos")` still points to the default repo defined in the image, and I have to change the repo manually when using `install.packages()`)... did I miss a step somewhere?

Comment: For me `getOption("repos")` returns `"https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/2021-05-17"` and I'm running `rocker/r-ver:4.0.5` at the core. Maybe that helps a bit with comparing what may be going on.

Comment: Actually I tried to change this now too and have run into the same problem. Did you find a solution @niclow?

Comment: Unfortunately not, my workaround has been to include a .Rprofile in a mounted project directory and restart R to load it immediately after starting the container.

Comment: FWIW: I have now transitions to using this file `/usr/local/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site`. I can change the link in there to the mirror I want and it persists.