# Error installing packages in Rstudio

Tags: r, install.packages

I have R 3.2.2 setup installed in my system,with RStudio version 0.99.489. When I tried to install `rJava` package,

```
install.packages("rJava")
```

I am getting following Error:

> Warning in install.packages :
>     downloaded length 4878 != reported length 200
>     Error in install.packages : subscript out of bounds

But if I run the below command before installing any package,it works fine, but I don't want to do this every time I install a package.

```
options(repos=structure(c(CRAN="http://cran.us.r-project.org")))
```

Comment: How is this Rstudio related?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set default CRAN mirror permanent in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475102/set-default-cran-mirror-permanent-in-r)

Comment: Could this be due to a corporate firewall/proxy?

Comment: Can help me with this related post pleasE? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61200536/r-unable-to-install-r-packages-cannot-open-the-connection

Answer (score 0):

You can stick the line you want executed at every startup in your .Rprofile file which should be in your home directory. I have 3.2.3 version of R and that worked; however I do get a warning message about using a non-http version of the site.

Similarly to you, I was finding the original repository the system was using was failing to install the packages--not finding the package or downloading a file with too few bytes, perhaps because of a transient problem. You might want to consider not putting this in your .Rprofile file or commenting the line outin case this is a temporary workaround.