# install.packages fails in knitr document: "trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror"

Tags: r, knitr

Using the following code I got the data I wanted, but for some reason I can't figure out `knitr` doesn't let me compile a PDF document, as shown further below:

My code:

```
install.packages("weatherData")
library(weatherData)
istanbul <- getWeatherForDate("Istanbul",
                              start_date = Sys.Date() - 41, 
                              end_date = Sys.Date())
```

Works out with no problem but I get the following message trying compile the PDF:

```
Quitting from lines 3-31 (ist_weather.spin.Rmd) 
Error in contrib.url(repos, type) : 
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> eval -> install.packages -> grep -> contrib.url
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Knitr produces a R session, without a default cran mirror unless you specifically asked for one. We tend to forget we need to set up CRAN for every R session when we use Rstudio because it takes care of it, but only for interactive use, not for knitr.

You could try specifying a mirror as a `install.packages` argument:

```
install.packages("weatherData",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Alternatively, you could set up your default CRAN mirror in your `.Rprofile`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475102/set-default-cran-mirror-permanent-in-r).

That said, **it is not a good idea to install packages through a knitr document that you will probably compile several times**. You should assume people know how to install a missing package if needed, or at least test whether the package is installed before installing it again

```
if(!require(weatherData)) install.packages("weatherData",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Comment: Interesting - can you explain *why* there is no default CRAN mirror in the new environment?

Comment: I actually meant R session, not environment. Sorry for that. This is just a default R behavior we tend to forget when we use Rstudio, because it takes care of it.

Comment: No worrys, I was not confused about "environment" vs. "session" (this was clear from the context). However, I didn't know that RStudio is involved in setting such options. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: You can convert the package install code into a comment. This eliminates the error and also gives the user a hint about the package installation.
`#install.packages (" weatherData ", repos =" http://cran.us.r-project.org ")`

Comment: I just started using R for the first time 5 minutes ago and the first thing I have to do is *Google an obscure error message so I can configure the package download mirror??* Wtf are they smoking?

Answer (score 31):

You must set the CRAN repository in your R. To do so, launch R or RStudio. in the R terminal run following codes.

```
r = getOption("repos")
r["CRAN"] = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"
options(repos = r)
install.packages("weatherData")
```

Above code defines CRAN repository in the R and in next package installation no need to define again.

Alternative way is to simply run `install.packages("weatherData", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")`. However, with the second solution the repository not set and you must pass it as a parameter in every package installation.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly,

It would not work for me because I installed packages, and these lines of code were interrupting the knit function. When I removed all lines containing installing packages (and used the most updated R and R Markdown available) this error went away.