# R code on separate lines from knitr in beamer

Tags: r, knitr, beamer

How do I get the R code below to print on separate lines?
It seems like this should be fairly simple.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{
<<eval=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, tidy=FALSE,error=FALSE,    echo=TRUE, results='asis'>>=
install.packages('reshape2')
install.packages('car')
install.packages('pastecs')  
@ 
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: deleting the `\frame{}` seems to work.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, but when `eval = FALSE` most of your other options are irrelevant (`message`, `warning`, `error`, and `results` will only apply to evaluated code).

Comment: OK, I see that, but I want to include these commands as part of a beamer slide...so don't I need to put them in a frame somehow?

Comment: Looking at [Yihui's examples](https://gist.github.com/yihui/1803930), he seems to always use fragile frames. If you do `\begin{frame}[fragile] ... \end{frame}` it seems to work. If you're not a LaTeX expert you may prefer authoring in Rmarkdown - you can still [compile to Beamer](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/beamer_presentation_format.html).

Comment: Using `install.packages` in a `knitr` document is a bad idea, see the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186983/cannot-compile-rmarkdown-document/35187295) and the suggested duplicate.

Comment: @CL. it has `eval = FALSE` here, so no matter.