# Error when trying to knit html in R markdown

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

Below is the error I am getting:

> ```
> Quitting from lines 46-48 (lesson3_student.rmd) 
> Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") : 
>   trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
> Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> install.packages -> contrib.url
> In addition: Warning message:
> In in_dir(opts_knit$get("root.dir") %n% input_dir(), evaluate::evaluate(code,  :
>   You changed the working directory to /Users/Madiyar/Desktop/Facebook Data (probably via setwd()). It will be restored to /Users/Madiyar/Downloads. See the Note section in ?knitr::knit
> Execution halted
> ```

Thanks for help

Comment: Please don't put `install.packages(…)` code in Rmd documents. Most folks want to manage their own package library.

Answer (score 2):

The error seems fairly clear to me; you're `"trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror"`; the problem is that knitting runs in non-interactive mode. Try putting

```
options(repos="https://cran.rstudio.com" )
```

in your code. I would say by the way that in knitted code you should probably *not*

- run `install.packages()` (as @hrbrmstr says in the commenbts, "[m]ost folks want to manage their own package library")
- call `setwd()` to set your working directory manually

Comment: comments are technically not for "thank yous" -- if you want to convey your appreciation, accept the answer (click on the checkmark) and/or upvote

Comment: The problem is not that `knitr` uses "non-interactive mode", it's because RStudio is not involved. See [scoa's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969024/install-packages-fails-in-knitr-document-trying-to-use-cran-without-setting-a).