# R Markdown Error trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror

Tags: r

I'm trying to use R Markdown and I keep getting the same error
Error in contrib.url (repos, "source")
tring to use Cran without setting a mirror
Calls .. withVisible ->eval ->eval ->install.packages -> contrib.url
Execution halted.
I have used the following suggestions from Stack answers and keep getting the same error. The following suggestion were.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [install.packages fails in knitr document: "trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969024/install-packages-fails-in-knitr-document-trying-to-use-cran-without-setting-a)

Comment: I was able to get the answer from the referenced / linked from @MikaelJagan .  Thank you!