# Error keeps popping up when trying to compile in RStudio

Tags: r, compilation

This keeps popping up in Render when I try to compile my R code. Someone please help. I have no idea how to fix this

```
Error in `contrib.url()`:
! trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Backtrace:
 1. utils::install.packages("ggplot2")
 2. utils::contrib.url(repos, "source")
Execution halted
```

I have already tried setting my Primary CRAN repository to a geolocation near me but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Does this prior question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969024/install-packages-fails-in-knitr-document-trying-to-use-cran-without-setting-a