# How can I knit my .rmd file into pdf or Word?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

Suddenly I am no longer able to knit my .rmd files from R-Studio into Word or pdf. I already tried uninstalling everything (two times) and read a lot of threads here but I still can`t get it working. It says:

```
Error in `contrib.url()`:
! trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Backtrace:
 1. utils::install.packages("lmtest")
 2. utils::contrib.url(repos, "source")
```

I think it may have something to do with the fact that I also no longer able to set a working directory, it instantly switches back to the default directory. What can I do? Please, I am no longer able to hold back my anger.

I uninstalled R and R-Studio two times in order to be able to knit my files. I also copied my whole code into an old file which I was able to knit into Word. But as soon as I tried knitting my new code it suddenly doesnt work.

Comment: Welcome RRvbin! Not sure if I can help but I can try. Are you able to install the package lmtest outside the .Rmd file?

Comment: Does the document knit after removing the install.packages line? Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33970452/11856430) answer; if you really need the install packages function, maybe specify the CRAN link?