# Why can't I knit my RMarkdown file with the dlookr package in the source?

Tags: r, package, r-markdown, cran, dlookr

I am using the dlookr package in my project and cannot knit my RMarkdown file while the code for installing and loading the dlookr package is in the source. This is the error I am getting:

```
Quitting from lines 12-27 [setup] (Final-Project.Rmd)
Error:
! package or namespace load failed for 'dlookr':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'kableExtra', details:
  call: !is.null(rmarkdown::metadata$output) && rmarkdown::metadata$output %in% 
  error: 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
Backtrace:
 1. base::library(dlookr)
 2. base::tryCatch(...)
 3. base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 4. base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 5. value[[3L]](cond)
Execution halted"
```

The code in lines 12-27 is just different packages I am loading. Here is a screenshot of the code chunk:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx2Gz.png)

I tried solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969024/install-packages-fails-in-knitr-document-trying-to-use-cran-without-setting-a) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475102/set-default-cran-mirror-permanent-in-r). I checked my Global options and my mirror is already set to "Global (CDN) - RStudio", nothing in my secondary repositories section. Also, I tried the various commands suggested by R but still cannot seem to knit my file.

Comment: Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). You should not be installing packages in an RMarkdown document. You should install packages outside of the document itself, presumably the same way you installed all those other non-base R packages you are using. Try also running `install.packages("kableExtra")` to get the latest version of that package since that's where the error seems to be coming from.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug in `kableExtra`, which is being loaded because `dlookr` imports it.

`kableExtra:::.onLoad()` has this test:

```r
if (!is.null(rmarkdown::metadata$output) && rmarkdown::metadata$output %in% 
        c("ioslides_presentation", "slidy_presentation", "gitbook", 
            "bookdown::gitbook", "radix_article", "radix::radix_article", 
            "distill_article", "distill::distill_article")) {
        options(kableExtra.html.bsTable = TRUE)
    }
```

In your document, `rmarkdown::metadata$output` contains more than one entry, so `rmarkdown::metadata$output %in% ...` ends up containing more than one value.

The workaround for this bug is simply to make sure the `output` section in your YAML at the start of your document only contains one output format.  For example, these would be fine:

```
output: html_document
```

or

```
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
```

but this would trigger the error:

```
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
```

Comment: I think this bug has been fixed in a suggested change to `kableExtra`, but it hasn't been merged into the main version.  So you could install the patched version from Github instead.  The trouble is, there are a lot of suggested changes, and I'm not sure which version to suggest installing.