# About Knitting RMD file

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

While Knitting RMD file in word, execution halted due to some error in contrib.url(). It says trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
It also has two backtrace:

1. utils::install.packages(tidyverse)
   utils::contrib.url(repos,'source')
   I am trying to knit a RMD file. I am doing it for the first time so I take help of internet and do as the video suggests.I am expecting a word output for this RMD file The knitting conducts for first few lines and says quitting from 19-24 (unnamed Chunk-1)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Installing a package is a one-time affair.  I can't think of a reason why you would need to do it (without additional checks) when knitting a markdown document.  Once the package is installed, you make it available with `library(<package name>)`.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a *minimal reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, we need to see your markdown document (and maybe more), not just an error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [install.packages fails in knitr document: "trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969024/install-packages-fails-in-knitr-document-trying-to-use-cran-without-setting-a)