# R commander not openning in Mac due to error in structure

Tags: r, xquartz, r-commander

I have installed the new version of R along with the new version of XQuartz.
After that, I have restarted my computer.

I am not being able to open R commander, the following message comes up:

> When loading the Rcmdr package, the following alert comes up: Erro:
>   package or namespace load failed for 'Rcmdr':  .onAttach falhou em
>   attachNamespace() para 'Rcmdr', detalhes:   chamada:
>   structure(.External(.C_dotTcl, ...), class = "tclObj")   erro: [tcl]
>   failed to allocate font due to internal system font engine problem.

My system is composed of:

macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

R version 3.5.1

XQuartz 2.7.11

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: I'm also having this problem after upgrading brew. For now, I could install packages by setting a mirror permanently. It will avoid the GUI for selecting mirror: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475102/set-default-cran-mirror-permanent-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when working with the `downscale.raster()` function from "**spatialEco**": `Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj") :[tcl] failed to allocate font due to internal system font engine problem.`

Solved by installing the "**tcltk2**" package and updating "**spatialEco**".

Comment: Did you experience the issue on Mac too? Looking around I have found that all errors people report happened on Macs, however, in my case, it happens in CentOS 8.

Comment: Yap, MacOS Catalina 10.15.7