# R in command line not installing packages

Tags: r, ubuntu, install.packages

R in command line is not installing any packages. Have tried changing repos but packages do not stay installed. Everything works fine in Rstudio. This is an issue for when working with mapDamage

Have changed the repository. Uninstalled and reinstalled R multiple times.

```
> install.packages("gam")
Installing package into ‘/home/gf/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘gam’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
```

Changed the repository to "http://cran.rstudio.com" and it can install but as soon as I leave the R window it reverts back to the original repository and no longer works.

Comment: A networking issue. Maybe you are behind a firewall or proxy.

Comment: Any help on how to get around it?

Comment: That is not R-related at all.   You may have to google for 'how to configure a proxy' or alike.  Maybe start with your local help desk...

Answer (score 0):

You could [try a different CRAN mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8475208/5783745)

e.g.

```
options(repos=structure(c(CRAN="https://cran.csiro.au/")))
```

Then try to install?