# R doesn't let me knit a code into word format

Tags: r, knitr, tinytex

I'm getting an error as following.

[image]

I tried loading this package again but it is still version 0.12.

The following is the code output from `getOption("repos")`

```
CRAN 
"https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2019-04-15"
```

Comment: Looks like you are installing packages from a CRAN snapshot taken on 2019-04-15 which probably does not contain package versions released after that date.

Comment: @stefan 2019-April snapshot doesn't seem too old. How do you suggest I correct this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475102/set-default-cran-mirror-permanent-in-r or https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004067074-Managing-Packages-with-RStudio

Comment: @stefan I'm using microsoft R open. Could it be that?

Comment: Yep.  I'm not familiar with MS R Open but from the [docs](https://mran.microsoft.com/rro): "... the CRAN repository is configured to point to a specific CRAN repository snapshot." However as far as I got it you could change the date via [checkpoint](https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/reproducibility#timemachine)