# Suppress graph output of a function

Tags: r

How can I suppress the output of a function? In this case, the output i want to suppress is a plot that is automatically produced, even when i assign the function call to an object. For example, if I run:

```
require(sensemakr)
estimate <- 0.091321        
est_se <- 0.008321
dof <- 10000

sense_df <- sensemakr::ovb_contour_plot(estimate = estimate,
                                        se = est_se,
                                        dof = dof)
```

I get the values I want in `sense_df` but it also prints the below plot
[image]

This is suboptimal as all the code is part of a markdown file and i'm using the results in `sense_df` to make my own plot in the next chunk. So the automatic printing of this plot is just a bad example of what I go on to make.

I've tried following the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723034/suppress-output-of-a-function) to use `capture.output`, `invisible`, or `sink` but none seem to work.

**EDIT 1:**

The function is even overriding `{r, fig.show = "hide"}` at the beginning of my chunk.

**EDIT 2:**

I have also attempted to follow the suggestion [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759130/disable-plot-display-in-r/24762900#24762900). Wrapping the function call in `dev.off` returns the error `'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`, and wrapping it in `pdf(file = NULL)` does prevent the plot from showing up but there is still a plot-sized print in the output, just no actual plot within it. E.g.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting an `invisible()` around the code?

Comment: I have and it didn't work. Will edit post to make that clear

Comment: Maybe `dont_plot <- capture.output(.)`.

Comment: Try this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759130/disable-plot-display-in-r/24762900#24762900

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable plot display in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759130/disable-plot-display-in-r)

Comment: Thanks for these ideas. I have attempted them all but to no avail -- have edited post to document the troubleshooting steps i've tried and results

Comment: I'd try editing the function or making your own version. [Here's the code on Github](https://github.com/carloscinelli/sensemakr/blob/0fa610909e4bb1082b274cd28673fe5b3b68e8cd/R/ovb_plots.R#L337). Looks like the output you want is generated between lines 367 and 460, everything after that is plotting stuff you can ignore.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I think that's the right way forward