# How to prevent marrangeGrob opening a graphics device

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

Take the following example:

```
library(gridExtra)
pl <- lapply(1:11, function(.x) plot(1:10, rnorm(10), main=paste("plot", .x)))
ml <- marrangeGrob(pl, nrow=2, ncol=2)
```

The second line will open a graphics device but there is nothing in it. It will just stay open. I could close it simply with dev.off() or clicking the 'x'. However, I am interested in finding out how to prevent it opening in the first place. Is there a way? Or is ther another package that could do this without the device showing up?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the graphics device is showing up but I can point out some issues in your code and suggest an alternative way.

Your code returns `NULL` rather than storing the plots. You need to use the following approach (which is very troublesome) to store a `plot` object:

```
# set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(147)

plot.new() # clears the previous plots 
plot(1:10, rnorm(10), main = "test") # creates a scatter plot
p <- recordPlot() # stores the plot
p # accesses the plot
```

Let's say we managed to store 11 plots, the `marrangeGrob(pl, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)` command tries to arrange 4 objects (2 rows x 2 columns). You need to get rid of either `nrow=2` or `ncol=2`.

My suggestion would be to use `ggplot2` for more flexible and elegant plots in collaboration with `grid.arrange`, which doesn't open up the extra graphics window:

```
# import packages
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra) # for grid.arrange

# simple wrapper to create multiple plots
my_ggplot <- function(no, x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10)) {
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    labs(title = paste("MY GGPLOT", no), x = "x-axis label", y = "y-axis label")
}

# build and store the plots
p1 <- my_ggplot(1)
p2 <- my_ggplot(2)
p3 <- my_ggplot(3)
p4 <- my_ggplot(4)

# arrange the plots in a grid with 2 colums
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have found the solution for you, I got it from this post [Disable GUI, graphics devices in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339630/disable-gui-graphics-devices-in-r)

Put the following at the beginning of your script:

```
options(device=pdf)
```

The disadvantage though is that it creates a empyt pdf `Rplots.pdf` in your current working directory, but it prevents the graphic device from showing up.